# Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_avx2.so or libmkl_def.so. In Google Colab

Tags: anaconda, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run an external library in Google's Colab.
The library belongs to Anaconda's PyTorch Channel.

After downloading Conda and installing the library as following:

```
!wget -c https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh
!bash ./Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -u -p /usr/local/
!conda install -c pytorch target_library
```

And adding Conda's Lib to the system path

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/usr/local/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/")
import target_library
```

The library is being imported, however after executing some methods from the library the Colab session crashes including the following in run time logs:

```
 Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_avx2.so or libmkl_def.so.
```

Although there exists multiple question on Stack overflow to address this problem. They all don't consider Colab environment.

Note that running the same code using command line i.e.

```
 !python -c "..."
```

Or using python-cell-magic command

```
 %%python
```

The code executes normally.

Any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I tried to install faiss on Google Colab.
This occurred when I tried to install the cpu-version faiss but then use gpu-version instead.

But now it's solved by simply removing all of these dependent libraries and install the version you want again.

For example, if you have tried to install both faiss and faiss-gpu and get this error,

try:

```
!pip uninstall faiss-gpu
!pip uninstall faiss
```

then install it again. (At least it worked in my situation)

```
!pip uninstall faiss-gpu
```

This idea is from: 
[Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: while trying to import gensim package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388707/intel-mkl-fatal-error-while-trying-to-import-gensim-package)

In short, I think the reason why this error occurs might be some library dependency problem.